# Can we call swing application through javafx login page

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2

I have an login page in javafx and I want to open the swing application by validating the user id and password. Can we do that.

Javafx version is 2.2. Java swing application is in jdk 1.5 version. Can we do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure JDK 1.5 won't support JavaFX 2, though I haven't tried it. JDK 1.5 reached end of life more than 5 years ago.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you mean by "calling" the Swing application. You could launch it as a separate application. You could tell it to display through whatever API it makes available. It really depends entirely on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to launch a swing application via javafx login page ?